# Does Jersey support dollar sign in Path annotation of JAX-RS?

Tags: java, regex, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to be able to access the following rest URLs:

- http://localhost:9998/helloworld
- http://localhost:9998/helloworld/$count

The first URL works fine.  I am having trouble with the $count URL using Jersey implementation of JAX-RS.

Here is the code for the resource.

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("\\$count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage(
            @PathParam("\\$count") String count) {

        return "Hello count";
    }
}
```

I've also tried "$count" in both @Path and @PathParam but that didn't work either.

Note:  If I remove the dollar sign from all the code above then it works fine for the URL localhost:9998/helloworld/count.  However I need the dollar sign to be there in the URL because this will be an OData producer application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the $ sign has semantic meaning within the URL encoding spec. I can't imagine that you can use it in a regular URL without encoding it.

Comment: The dollar sign is legal to use in a URL without encoding.  It is heavily used in the Open Data Protocol, which is a rest based protocol.  See [link](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.  Placing the dollar sign in a character class did the trick.

```
@GET
@Path("{count : [$]count(/)?}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getClichedMessageCount(
        @PathParam("count") String count) {

    return "Hello count";
}
```

The above matches the following URLs.

- localhost:9998/helloworld/$count
- localhost:9998/helloworld/$count/
- localhost:9998/helloworld/$count?$filter=blah
- localhost:9998/helloworld/$count/?$filter=blah

Answer (score 1):

Dollar signs are special characters in URLs, and need to be encoded as such, I'm afraid:

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

The character you're looking for is %24, if you're interested, though if you're in java, reading up on the [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class might be worth it. I've not played with Jersey, but Java is more than capable of doing the hard work for you here.

Comment: Encoding the dollar sign is not mandatory. Dollar sign is identified as a reserved character in the URI RFC, RFC 3986[¹](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2 "RFC 3986 sec. 2.2") because it has special meaning to some specific URI schemes (notably `gopher:`). It has no special meaning in the `http:` URI scheme.

Comment: Rohaq, I believe MetaEd is correct.  See the [Open Data Protocol](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions) for a rest-based protocol that makes heavy use of the dollar sign in URLs.

Comment: Ah, ok, my mistake then! It's probably still worth encoding the URI properly though to avoid further issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong slash in the @Path

```
@GET
@Path("/$count")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getClichedMessage(
        @PathParam("\\$count") String count) {

    return "Hello count";
}
```

Also that is not the correct way to use PathParam.  If you are trying to retrieve the value after /helloworld you should do the following

```
@GET
@Path("/{$count}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getClichedMessage(
        @PathParam("$count") String count) {

    return "Hello count";
}
```

Edit
 Couldn't get it to work with a $

```
@Path("count") // works
@Path("/count") // works
@Path("\\count") // does not work
@Path("$count") // does not work
@Path("/$count") // does not work
```

Comment: Hi Michael.  Tried the first code example you suggested but it didn't work.  The second example is not applicable since I need to match the literal "$count" string.

Comment: @Jerome You're right, it still doesn't work after fixing the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Question is long solved but maybe this will help someone in the future looking for a similar problem.

The way we found when dealing with this problem is to write a class which replaces the encoded sign back to the dollar sign itself. We registered the class in our RestEasyClient.

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ClientRequestFilter{

@Override
public void filter(ClientRequestContext context) throws IOException {
   //replace uri in context...
   String uri = context.getUri();
   //regex to replace $ sign in uri
   //set new uri in context so request goes to correct url
   context.setUri(uri);
}
```